# call a build function in StatefullWidget after finish the Future function

Tags: flutter, async-await, future

i need to call and get the result from an async function before build the widget in statefulWidget in flutter, i tried to do like this, but it didn't work:

```
 @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
             loadDocument(details).whenComplete((){
              setState(() {});
            });
         vid = YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(details);
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print("from details in build widget");
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(name.toString()),
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
body : Center(child: PDFViewer(document: controller.document)))
```

in this example, first thing call the function (loadDocument), after that call the (build) methode for widget, and then show the result after (whenComplete) has been finished, but what i need is to only call the build function after (whenComplete) finish....

this code for loadDocument

```
 PDFDocument document = PDFDocument();

  loadDocument(String url) async {
    try {
      return document = await PDFDocument.fromURL(
          url);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FutureBuilder to build your ui based on the different Future states:

```
FutureBuilder<*Your future return type*>(
    future: *Your future*, 
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<*Your future return type*> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // Handle future resolved case
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        // Handle future error case
      } else {
        // Handle future loading case
      }
   },
)
```

You can read more about FutureBuilder here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: it doesn't work, because this function doesnt return anything important for me, i have edit the question and add more details, to be more obvious